# How to include parameter constraints in the Levenberg-Marquardt algorithm?

Tags: least-squares, optimization, gradient-descent, algorithms

Every resource I found online doesn’t say what to do if the constraints aren’t satisfied. If my updated parameters is given by:
$$\theta_{k+1} = \theta_k - (JJ^T + \lambda I)^{-1}Jr, $$ where J is the gradient, $\lambda$ is the damping factor and $r=C-C^*$ is the minimiser function ($C^*$ is the real value we are calibrating to). If one of the parameters is $\omega$ and I have the constraint, $0<\omega<2$, what am I supposed to do in my algorithm when $\omega = 3.5$ in the calculated $\theta_{k+1}$.

Comment: Among the possibilities are penalties, transformations, trust regions, and forgetting about the constraint altogether.

Comment: I have to have constraints as some of the parameters I’m estimating is volatility (variance). What do you mean by trust regions in this context and how can it be implemented for each parameter so they have constraints

Comment: oh, for a simple box constraint like that, you can just go less than the full distance along the search direction $\delta_k = \theta_{k+1}-\theta_k$. Let $\eta$ be the step size that makes it such that $\theta_{k}^\omega + \eta\delta_k^\omega = 2$. Then just set $\theta_{k+1} = \theta_k + \delta_k$. From then on, so long as the search direction is pointing in the positive direction for $\omega$, zero out that element of the search direction and take a full step. You may be interested in popular implementations of the L-BFGS-B algorithm, which is available on Wikipedia.

Comment: Alternatively, reparameterize $\omega$ to be real valued using a shifted sigmoid function (though this will make convergence slow if the optimal value of $\omega$ is on the boundary).

Comment: Is the upper limit of $2$ meaningful?  If it's artificial or arbitrary, setting it as a constraint probably is not a good approach unless you plan simply is to flag all estimates on the boundary and deal with them in some other fashion.

Comment: @whuber The upper limits are arbitrary, but the lower bounds aren't. Mainly that if parameters break the lower boundary, you get situations that don't make sense, i.e. negative variance.

Comment: For statistical reasons, it's usually better to use the log variance or its reciprocal as the parameter.  That automatically solves your problem: no constraints are needed.  But that's not what you're asking: your question explicitly concerns the *upper* constraint on $\omega,$ which is the one that appears to be artificial.

Comment: I have nothing to contribute to this discussion other than to say: "Great name btw". MY MATH SPECIALIST